# C++ Screen capture fail after hundreds repetitions on Windows: memory leak?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, screen-capture, bitblt

I use a function which captures a screen using the `BitBlt` mehtod and can then return a `HBITMAP`.

```
int screenCapture() {
    int width = 1000;
    int height = 700;

    HDC hdcTemp, hdc;
    BYTE* bitPointer;

    hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    BITMAPINFO bitmap;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap.bmiHeader);
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&bitPointer), NULL, NULL);
    SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
    DeleteDC(hdcTemp);
    return (int)bitPointer[0];
}
```

Here, the function only returns the first value of the pixels array.
Actually, it works fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
        cout << i << ": " << screenCapture() << endl;
    }
```

But when I try to loop this, an error is generated after a few hundred rounds (a little over 900 for me), an `Access violation reading location` error.

I also noticed that if I reduced the values of `width` and `height`, then the error took longer to be called.

I am a true beginner and I do not know where the error may come, but it would look like a memory problem, right?

Comment: You should `DeleteObject(hBitmap)`

Comment: Do you eventually call DeleteObject on the bitmap handle?  Generally you want to save the old object when you select a new object into a dc and then select that old object back when you're done.  It may not matter since you delete the dc, but another potential leak.

Comment: @AlexK. @RetiredNinja I tried with `DeleteObject` but I did not do it the right way. Now, it works fine and I have no more "access violation reading location" error, thank you!

Comment: "something fails" + "after a period of time" + "on Windows" + "involving graphics" = "GDI object leak"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was stated in comments, you are leaking your `HBITMAP`, and also the original `HBITMAP` that was already in the `HDC` before you called `SelectObject()`.  Whenever you use `SelectObject()`, you must always restore the original value (you don't own it).

And don't forget to do error checking!

Try this:

```
int screenCapture()
{
    int result = -1;

    int width = 1000;
    int height = 700;

    HDC hdcTemp, hdc;
    BYTE* bitPointer;

    hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    if (hdc != NULL)
    {
        hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        if (hdcTemp != NULL)
        {
            BITMAPINFO bitmap;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap.bmiHeader);
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
            bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

            HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bitPointer, NULL, NULL);
            if (hBitmap != NULL)
            {
                HBITMAP hPrevBitmap = SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap);

                BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                result = (int) bitPointer[0];

                SelectObject(hdcTemp, hPrevBitmap);
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }

            DeleteDC(hdcTemp);
       }

       ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
    }

    return result;
}
```